# extract date only from pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have this column in pandas df:
'''

```
full_date
2020-12-02T08:11:30-0600
2020-12-02T02:11:50-0600
2020-12-03T08:56:29-0600
```

'''

I only need the date, hoping to have this column:
'''

```
date
2020-12-02
2020-12-02
2020-12-03
```

'''

I have tried to find the solution from previous questions, but still failed. If anyone can help, I will appreciate that a lot. thanks.

Comment: try: `full_date.dt.date`

Answer (score 1):

In case your column is not a `datetime` type, you can convert it to that and then use the `.dt` accessor to get just the date:

```
>>> df["date"] = df["full_date"].pipe(pd.to_datetime, utc=True).dt.date
>>> print(df)
                  full_date        date
0  2020-12-02T08:11:30-0600  2020-12-02
1  2020-12-02T02:11:50-0600  2020-12-02
2  2020-12-03T08:56:29-0600  2020-12-03
```

Comment: I have tried that one, the result was error:

ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True

Comment: just added utc=True and it worked. thanks

Comment: Glad you figured it out! I'll update the post with that argument for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the datetime very easily using this python code, if suitable.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
var = "2020-12-02T08:11:30-0600"
parseddate = parse(var).date()
```